# .htaccess redirect all subdomains to one directory, and preserve url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have spend most of the afternoon googling this one and cant seem to get it to work at all (I am a bit rusty with htaccess!)

Basically I have a site, and every user registered has a subdomain (e.g. userA.example.com, userB.example.com)

I have been using a php script to register these subdomains, but now with over 500(!) subdomains, I am moving to a new server and thought I could possibly implement a new system.

I would basically like any subdomain appended to the domain to point to a single folder and keep the original url in the browser's address bar, so that I don't have to use server resources to register a new subdomain for every user!

I have already setup the wildcard DNS required for this.

I am using the following code to perform the redirect, but the address still changes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.XXXX\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.XXXX\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXX.com/frontend/ [L,NC]
```

This does redirect absolutely fine, but I cannot figure out a way to preserve the original URL with subdomain.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Should be pointing to `/frontend/username` or `/username` ?

Comment: @JustinIurman just pointing to /frontend/ the php scrapes the username from the subdomain portion of the URL

Comment: Shouldn’t this be working fine if you just give a relative rewrite path instead of an absolute URL …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first enable `mod_proxy` via your Apache config otherwise URL will change since you're changing domain name here.

Once `mod_proxy` is enabled try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.XXXX\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://XXXX.com/frontend/ [L,NC,P]
```

Comment: I have enabled mod_proxy however I seem to be getting directed to subdomain.xxxx.com/frontend/ which doesnt exist. Perhaps my mod_proxy settings are incorrect

Comment: Do you want to be forwarded to `http://xxxx.com/frontend/` only? How will you know from which subdomain it came from?

Comment: No, sorry, lets say 'userA' goes to userA.xxxx.com the url should remain as userA.xxxx.com but load from xxxx.com/frontend/

Comment: Brilliant, that works! The only issue is any references to files, images etc are pointing to userA.xxxx.com/frontend which doesnt exist, but I guess I can just update all of these to absolute urls, unless there is another way to do it?

Comment: Theres some strange behaviour with that now, every file is being returned as /frontend/index.html!

Comment: Strange, this actually was meant to make it more restrictive by not allowing files and directories to be proxied.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler method of handling any complex redirection is to use PHP. In the server config file or an .htaccess file, use the `FallbackResource` directive to send all URL requests to a single PHP file. In that file, use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the hostname and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the original URI. Then you can use

```
header('Location: https://subdomain.example.com/');
```

to redirect to any calculated URL you wish.